# Startup image not working

Tags: html, css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need some help regarding the Startup image.

The App should show a login panel . And i would like to set a Background image from the Startup (loading indicator) until the Login panel appears with the same Background image in full screen .

I tried 4 Methods to do it but no success
First Method : 
I set a style block in the index.html:

```
    <style type="text/css">                
shtml, body {                    
height: 100%;                    
background-color:#FFFFFF;                    
background-image: url(resources/startup/ios/Ipad_Landscape_1024x748.png);                    background-position: center;                    
background-repeat: no-repeat;                
}
```

-> the Problem is that the image will be loaded after the White Screen and Loading indicator and i don't know how to set it depending on the Orientation (Portrait , Landscape)

Second Method:

I wrote this in the index.html :

```
     <!-- startup image for web apps - iPad - landscape (748x1024)             
    Note: iPad landscape startup image has to be exactly 748x1024 pixels 
    (portrait, with contents rotated).--> 
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="resources/startup/ios/Ipad_Landscape_748x1024" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />                        
<!-- startup image for web apps - iPad - portrait (768x1004) -->            
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="resources/startup/ios/Ipad_Portrait_768x1004.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" />                        
<!-- startup image for web apps (320x460) -->            
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/iphone.png" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" />
```

--> No success

Third Method:

```
    /*    icon: {        
'57': 'resources/icons/ios/Icon_phone.png',        
'72': 'resources/icons/ios/Icon-72_Ipad.png',        
'114': 'resources/icons/ios/Icon-114.png',        
'144': 'resources/icons/ios/Icon-144_ipad@2x.png'   
 },*/               
fullscreen: true,                
glossOnIcon:true,    
isIconPrecomposed: true,    
startupImage: {        
'768x1004': 'resources/startup/ios/Ipad_Portrait_768x1004.png',        
'748x1024': 'resources/startup/ios/Ipad_Landscape_748x1024.png',    
},
```

--> Failed

The last one : I tried to add this line to the app.js

Code:

```
tabletStartupScreen:    'resources/startup/ios/Ipad_Landscape_748x1024.png',
```

--> failed

I need Help Please .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you access your app from an icon you put on homescreen or from Safari directly ? Because startup images only work in the former case.

Comment: Yes , from an icon .. I'm working on xCode / iOS Simulator

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try putting your image both in background of loading screen and first view(login page)? To put an image on loading page you can change CSS property of appLoadingIndicator in index.html like this:

```
    #appLoadingIndicator {
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 980px;
        height: 540px;
        background-image:url('resources/startup/ios/Ipad_Landscape_1024x748.png');
        -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
    }
```

Then use the same image as background for login view.

Comment: And What about the Orientation ? I wann make a login view and the startup image should exit as background of the login screen. How i can release it?

Comment: I haven't done it but using CSS background properties that should be possible because panel is infact a div which can have background image

Comment: We Suppose : When we start the app , instead of the white screen and loading indiactor, you see the Background image in full screen, then it pass to the login fields (With the same Background image as in first ) and you want to place the login fields separately not in the same panel , let we say in the bottom Area you make two entries one for the username (label and text field ) and with some spaces the second entry for password , in the right side of the first one in the same line (level) and Above (TOp of the screen in the middle a Title of the login: How would you do release it? thanks